# No options for Select deployment server in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to run a Java Spring project in NetBeans, and the following **Select deployment server** window opens:

[image: window]

But in that dropdown **Server** list there are no options available, although I have Tomcat running in the **Services** tab. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. This project was not created in NetBeans, it was imported from zip file. So I recreated the project as a web application and pasted the source files in the new project and it worked. When you create a web application, there's a step where you are asked about the server type. I chose Tomcat there. Also when you you create a project from scratch, NetBeans adds a file called nb-configuration.xml, where this choice is remembered. And in the initial project this file wasn't present.

Answer (score 1):

right click on project select properties and click on run set server from drop down of server list